# CSS Only Accordian Layout

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a block of text in my accordion layout only open when the radio button is checked. But I don't understand why the content is always visible. I only want to do this via HTML and CSS, but I am having difficulty. Can someone take a look and offer advice?

I've tried making the display to none, but it still is visible

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="accordian">
            <div class="accordian-item">
                <a href="#" class="heading">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <input type="radio" id="rd1" name="icon">
                        <label class="radio-label" for="rd1"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="title">Item 1

                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="content">
                    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos, facilis.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
$midnight: #2c3e50;
$clouds: #ecf0f1;
// General
html {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
// Layout
.row {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  height: 30em;
  max-width: 1900px;
  justify-content: center;
  .col {
    width: 20em;  
    height: 20em; 
    margin: auto;  
    &:last-child {
      margin-left: 2em;
    }
  }
}

/* Accordion styles */
.accordian {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 75rem;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 2rem;
 border-radius: 10px;
 overflow: hidden;
 // max-width:30em;
}

.accordian-item {
  position: relative;

  .heading{
        display: block;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: $midnight;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 1rem;
        position: relative;
        padding: 1.5rem 1.5rem 1.5rem 4rem;
        transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;

        @media (min-width: 40rem) {
            font-size: 1.2rem;
        }

        &:hover {
            color: darken($midnight, 10%);

            .icon {
                &:before,
                &:after {
                    background: $clouds;
                }
            }
        }
  }

  .icon {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 0;
        width: 3rem;
        height: 3rem;
        border: 2px solid $midnight;
        border-radius: 8px;
        transform: translateY(-50%);

        &:before,
        &:after {
            content: '';
            width: 1.25rem;
            height: 0.25rem;
            background: $midnight;
            position: absolute;
            border-radius: 3px;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        &:after {
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
                       rotate(90deg);
            z-index: -1;
        }
    }

  &.active{
    .heading {
            color: $midnight;
        }
    .icon {
            background: $clouds;

            &:before {
                background: green;
            }

            &:after {
                width: 0;
            }
        }
  }

  .radio-label {
      cursor: pointer;
   }

  input:checked{
   .content {
    max-height: 100vh;
    padding: 2rem 2rem;
    color: $midnight;
    background: $clouds;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    display:block;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    transition: all .1s;
        p {
            color: $midnight;
            margin: 2rem 2rem;
        }

        @media (min-width: 40rem) {
            padding-left: 4rem;
            line-height: 1.75;
        }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: We can't reproduce the sass here you have in your example, nor the bootstrap classes I see in there without their css included in a snippet. You might want to add a codepen or compiled css in here with the stuff required for the bootstrap classes as well so we have a full minimal example to reproduce. However if you'd like just a quick similar example of what it sounds like you're after [see here](https://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/jmdrre)

Comment: https://codepen.io/sri-go/pen/dybMGmw?editors=1100

Comment: Only inside the scoop where the input is located can be formatted in css.

Answer (score 1):

This won't be possible in CSS without some refactoring of your HTML.  There is no CSS selector that can access a parent.  There are selectors for targeting children and siblings though.

Here is a simplified standalone prototype showing how the tilde (~) selector can be used to target siblings.

```css
.accordion input[type=checkbox] {
  float: left;
}
.accordion .accordion-item .accordion-tab {
  display: none;
}
.accordion .accordion-item input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .accordion-tab {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <h3>Accordion item</h3>
    <div class="accordion-tab">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium voluptates velit, cupiditate et perspiciatis illum doloremque saepe nemo doloribus vero cumque, neque praesentium assumenda porro quaerat facere! Aperiam, dolores impedit?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something like this. Since you are using radio inout it will tigger only once. If you want to toggle use checkbox input type instead.

```css
html {
  background-color: #eee;
}
input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: #333;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  height: 30em;
  max-width: 1900px;
  justify-content: center;
}
.row .col {
  width: 20em;
  height: 20em;
  margin: auto;
}
.row .col:last-child {
  margin-left: 2em;
}
/* Accordion styles */
.accordian {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 75rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.accordian-item {
  position: relative;
}
.accordian-item .heading {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2c3e50;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1.5rem 1.5rem 1.5rem 4rem;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
@media (min-width: 40rem) {
  .accordian-item .heading {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
}
.accordian-item .heading:hover {
  color: #1a252f;
}
.accordian-item .heading:hover .icon:before, .accordian-item .heading:hover .icon:after {
  background: #ecf0f1;
}
.accordian-item .icon {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border: 2px solid #2c3e50;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.accordian-item .icon:before, .accordian-item .icon:after {
  content: '';
  width: 1.25rem;
  height: 0.25rem;
  background: #2c3e50;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 3px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.accordian-item .icon:after {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
.accordian-item.active .heading {
  color: #2c3e50;
}
.accordian-item.active .icon {
  background: #ecf0f1;
}
.accordian-item.active .icon:before {
  background: green;
}
.accordian-item.active .icon:after {
  width: 0;
}
.accordian-item .radio-label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.accordian-item .content {
  display: none;
}
.accordian-item input:checked + a + .content {
  max-height: 100vh;
  padding: 2rem 2rem;
  color: #2c3e50;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  transition: all 0.1s;
}
.accordian-item input:checked + a + .content p {
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin: 2rem 2rem;
}
@media (min-width: 40rem) {
  .accordian-item input:checked + a + .content {
    padding-left: 4rem;
    line-height: 1.75;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="accordian">
            <div class="accordian-item">
                <input type="radio" id="rd1" name="icon">
                <a href="#" class="heading">
                    <div class="icon">
                        <label class="radio-label" for="rd1"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="title">Item 1

                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="content">
                    <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos, facilis.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```